# Make 100€ out of 1€

Tags: mathematics, algebra, money

With the following trick you can turn 1€ into 100€:
$$
\begin{align}
1 \, €
&= 2 \, € \cdot 0.5 \, € \\
&= 200 \, \text{ct} \cdot 50 \, \text{ct} \\
&= 10 \, 000 \, \text{ct} = 100 \, €
\end{align}
$$

> Where did I cheat in this calculation?

Comment: you  can use the same trick to turn 100E into 1E

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Oh, now I know why my money always vanishes so quickly :-S

Comment: That’s a nice trick which I’ve never encountered before. I wonder if there are any economic formulae in which the square of money unit is a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot multiply,

> two same units to find the very same unit.